# KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError in Compose Preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-reflect

I have defined the Kotlin reflection dependency in my Gradle file as follows:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`

Within the App, reflection works just fine. However, when I use reflection within a Composable preview:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun MyComposablePreviewUsingReflection() {
    val foo = SomeClass::class.sealedSubclasses.size
}
```

I get the `kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError`. When I build the App and use reflection in a normal Composable (i.e., not a preview), reflection works just fine.

Is there a way to get reflection working in a Compose preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem will be fixed in Android Studio Flamingo.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240601093

Comment: As of Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1, it is "fixed" but doesn't appear to be functional, at least for sealed classes. `isSealed` returns false, and `sealedSubclasses` is always empty.